# Can not get attached cookie in ContainerRequestContext in Jersey

Tags: javascript, java, cookies, jersey

I have added a cookie using java script and i need to access it in my server side.Every REST request goes through this filter.

**Add cookies in JS**

```
document.cookie = "session-key="+session.getKey();
```

Cookie is added to the browser i have verified it.but when i access it in server side it wont list down.

**Server side sample code snippet**

```
@Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext){
    System.out.println(requestContext.getCookies());
    //added cookie is not list down
}
```

Also i have tried attached to the request header but nothing happened.

```
jqXhr.setRequestHeader('Set-Cookie', "session-key=1234567");
```

please let me know what went wrong.

Comment: Set-Cookie is for server->client. Cookie is for client->server

Comment: @peeskillet i tried it also but throw an `Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"`

Comment: Probably because you're not supposed to set cookies manually. The browser sends it automatically. Interaction: First client makes some request. then server send Set-Cookie header with response. Browser stores cookie internally. On next request it sends the Cookie.

Comment: but seems like browser wont send cookie created.i can not access in my server side.but when i go browser `Application/cookies` i can see it.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it has something to do with the AJAX call. I don't really work with lower level XHR, so I don't know if there is anything that needs to be tweaked or not in order for the browser to send the cookies. I know with some frameworks, you need to add a switch. Not sure with the lower level XHR. You can do a search